# External CSS Stylesheet not working

Tags: css

I have no idea why this HTML file is not formatted with the linked stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sticky Notes</title>
        <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“s.css” type=“text/css”/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class=“yellow”>
            <p>Make sticky notes with HTML/CSS.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The document path -- I have a folder StickyNotes with the files "s.css" and the above HTML file "sticky.html".

Here is the CSS:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #edeeb4;

}
.pink {
    background-color: #eeb4b4;

}
.green {
    background-color: #b4eec6;

}
.blue {
    background-color: #b4c0ee;
}
.grey {
    background-color: #dddee7;

}
```

Comment: It depends on where `s.css` is in the directory structure in relation to `sticky.html`. Are they in the same folder?

Comment: Also the quotes you pasted in look like 'fancy quotes'. I might try replacing them with standard single `'` or double `"` quotes.

Comment: Yes they are in the same folder @patrickberkeley

Comment: Maybe try using a relative path `href="./s.css"`.

Comment: Also, if you open the developer tools in your browser, do you see any errors?

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Apparently they were "fancy quotes," and changing them worked. I assumed that changing to plain text on TextEdit would ensure that they were standard quotes, but apparently not. Is there a way I could make sure I use standard quotes when editing HTML on TextEdit in the future?

Comment: Great! I don't know of a solid way to be sure the quotes aren't 'fancy'. I usually avoid pasting code in because it can have hidden characters that cause errors that are difficult to track down.

Comment: use editplus or notepad++ or VI or similar tools to edit code. Not sure what TextEdit is

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="s.css">
```

Its the more modern format. Also make sure that your css is not in another folder, in which case you'll also need to specify the folder path.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your double quotes use below code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s.css">`